# How do I change the first elements of a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array

```
[[-20,23],[-80,65], ... []]
```

and I need

```
[["20",23],["80",65], ... []]
```

I have no idea how to deal with it.

Here is my code:

```
@posts = Post.featured_post.where(new_follow: true)
posts = (@posts.map { |post| "-#{ post[:ss_group_id] }_#{ post[:post_id] }" }).join(',') # here make parameters for request
posts = '"' + posts + '"'

posts_response = get_request(code_constructor('API.get', { posts: posts },[])) # here is response from API

noexist_posts = @posts.pluck(:vk_group_id, :post_id) - (posts_response[0].map { |h| h.values_at('owner_id', 'id') })
              .map { |a| [a[0].abs.to_s, a[1]] } # here is what I want
```

I tried to find which posts don't exist.

Comment: What is the logic of change?

Comment: @WandMaker want to withdraw one array, that I have from @post.pluck() from another, that I have as response from API request. Formats are different

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". We expect to see something that gives us an idea of your effort toward solving your question. Stack Overflow isn't a "give me code site", it's a "help me fix my code" site. Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and then modify your question to give us a better idea what you've tried.

Comment: Also read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
result = your_array.map{|a| [a[0].abs.to_s),a[1]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more inefficient, but cooler looking alternative to regular reassignment:

```
x.map { |first, *rest| [first.abs.to_s, *rest] }
```

Comment: I was curious about the inefficiency so I benchmarked it. It's about 40% slower than the (destructive) reassignment method, but 5% faster than a non-destructive reassignment method (because of the `dup` overhead). Personally this is my favorite method and the overhead is negligible unless you have thousands of elements.

Comment: @Jordan, nice. Do you mind sharing the benchmark somewhere ([repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/ruby) for example)?

Comment: I've put it in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/83294acc5daea3b4ecbf (repl.it doesn't have the benchmark-ips gem so it wouldn't run).

Comment: P.S. FWIW I'm using Ruby 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason noone has posted the *"regular reassignment"* yet, so here it is (assuming you want to change the array in place):

```
x.each { |numbers| numbers[0] = numbers.first.abs.to_s }
```